# Connect Antenna Cable To Laptop Without TV Tuner

Tags: laptop, television

**Hey, how could I connect an antenna cable to a laptop without using a TV Tuner, in order to reproduce Live TV content? What would I need to do?
It's possible that while trying to do it without a Tuner I accidentally end up making a homemade version of it.**

Comment: This question is written in a way that precludes product recommendations. This site is for asking what product to purchase, not for general "is this possible and how do I do it?" hardware questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signals for over the air television, also known as antenna television are now digital in the USA. If you have a cable from an antenna, it is effectively collecting the free-air signals into that wire. There is nothing in a conventional computer/laptop that can decipher or process those signals.

You would absolutely have to have a means to convert those signals in order to view them as television video, which requires a tuner.

The same signals can be processed by a different piece of equipment, known as a spectrum analyzer. The display of such a device would be similar to that of an oscilloscope and would be of limited value.

Comment: Would it be possible to make an improvised Tuner, using old Television parts?

Comment: Especially not, if using old television parts, as today's television signals are digital and "yesterday's" television parts used analog components.

Comment: I didn't mean "old" like from years ago, I meant recent but unused parts.

Comment: It would be a fairly impressive accomplishment to reverse engineer a digital capable television to the point where you can separate the tuner components and provide for an output suitable for displaying on a laptop computer. Someone with those skills would likely create a tuner from discrete components available off-the-shelf, to ensure accuracy and reliability.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop does not have the hardware needed to receive TV signals, but you can get [a USB tuner like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015IL0FIW) rather than use a set-top-box type.